# Displaying objects in page frame in foxpro

Tags: database, foxpro

How to display objects in fox-pro page frame using display objects command?
I have already tried to use display objects like * to file *.txt but it only displayed the objects in the form (main objects) all the objects contained in the page frame container didn't show in the file.

I want to know how to display the objects in container like page frame to file for development purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Object Inspector tool that I built. It's described in this paper: http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Conference%20Sessions/Collections--Managing%20Information%20the%20Object-Oriented%20Way.pdf and can be downloaded with the examples for that session at http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/publications/conferencepapers.

Tamar